# Find the location an existing custom block

Tags: magento2, blocks

Please, forgive me for the probably dumb question but this the first time I use Magento.
I have been asked to make a simple change to an existing page (insert a few words of text).
I have been granted access to the system through a web interface.
After a couple of hours of "navigating" the Contents, I found that the page I need to access
is activated by the following block

{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"template="Magento_Theme::storelocator/XXXXXX.phtml"}}

XXXXXX is a specific name that I prefer to anonymize.
My questions are: How do I find the "real" code (the XXXXXX.phtml) file? 
Is it available and possibly editable from the same web interface? Or do I need to have the original file, modify it and upload (where in this case)?
Thanks in advance for any help,
Mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find this code in *Magento_Dir/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/storelocator/XXXXX.phtml*

If this help then hit like.

Thank you
Hiren Patel

Comment: But you can not edit code in this file because this is not good as per Magento standard.

Comment: You have to copy this file in app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name/Magento_Theme/templates/storelocator/XXXXXXX.phtml and there you can edit as prr your need.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is already very useful but my problem is also IF I can access that path from the web interface (that is through the browser) or if direct access to the host is required. If it is possible through the web interface, how do I find that file? Thanks again!

Comment: You can detect path of phtml file but you can not edit it through web interface.
For detect a path through web interface https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-enable-template-path-hints-magento-2.html

If this help you then hit like

Comment: Thanks! I accepted the answer. I hope it is equivalent to hit like. Thanks again!